# VirtualizingPanel not Virtualizing using WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, virtualization, viewbox

So no matter how hard I try I can't get virtualization in my view to work.

When I scroll through my Listbox, the items always keep populating from the top and carry on right to the bottom, rather than rendering what is on screen and just a bit above and bellow.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Bellow is the code for the Viewbox. A point of note:

I am using a Viewbox inside a ListBox and a grid inside the ViewBox. This is because my items populate in a similar way to text with word warping turned on - it populates horizontally until the width, then moves on to the next line.

My items in the ListBox are scalable, and there position in the view changes dynamically depending on the scale size, whilst also, the TextBlocks text dose not scale.

Not sure if that effects virtualization in a way I am unaware.

If that is not clear, I apologise and am happy to answer any questions. Thanks for your time:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LibraryBox"
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="4"
            Margin="0,-5,0,-10"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            Background="#1e1e1e"

            ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"

            VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
            VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
            VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
            VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"

            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"

            SelectionMode="Extended"
            SelectionChanged="LibraryBox_SelectionChanged" 
            MouseDoubleClick="LibraryBox_MouseDoubleClick">

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <!--#region scrollbar style-->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#990000"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="25"/>
            </Style>
            <!--#endregion-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
        </ListBox.Resources>

        <ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="ContextMenuItemEdit_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="ComicVine Scraper" Click="MenuItemScraper_Click"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="ContextMenuItemDelete_Click"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>

        <!--#region Group Style-->
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                                                FontWeight="Bold" 
                                                                Foreground="#dbdbdb" 
                                                                FontSize="16" 
                                                                FontFamily="Cordia New"
                                                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" 
                                                                FontSize="16" 
                                                                Foreground="#dbdbdb" 
                                                                FontStyle="Italic" 
                                                                Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                                                FontFamily="Cordia New"
                                                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <!--#endregion-->

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Viewbox Height="100" Width="70" Margin="2">
                        <Viewbox.LayoutTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=ZoomSlider}"
                                        ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=ZoomSlider}"/>
                        </Viewbox.LayoutTransform>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <!--This is for thumbnails-->
                            <Image x:Name="coverImage"
                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Source="{Binding CoverPath, Converter={StaticResource UriToBitmapConverter}, IsAsync=True}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="ReadMarkerBottom"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           Margin="-16,0,0,0"
                                           Fill="#fff"
                                           Width="32"
                                           Height="32"
                                           Loaded="CoverImage_Loaded"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="ReadMarkerTop"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           Margin="-16,0,0,0"
                                           Fill="#000"
                                           Width="30"
                                           Height="30"
                                           Loaded="CoverImage_Loaded"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>

                    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                   Width="120"
                                   Foreground="#dbdbdb"
                                   Background="Transparent"
                                   Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                   Loaded="Text_Loaded"
                                   FontFamily="Cordia New"
                                   FontWeight="Bold">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                   Width="120"
                                   Foreground="#dbdbdb"
                                   Background="Transparent"
                                   Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                   Loaded="IssueNumer_Loaded"
                                   FontFamily="Cordia New"/>
                    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                   Width="120"
                                   Foreground="#dbdbdb"
                                   Background="Transparent"
                                   Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                   Loaded="CountStack_Loaded"
                                   FontFamily="Cordia New"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: The ItemsPanel must support virtualization. WrapPanel does not.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Unfortunately it has lead to a new problem which is all the items are now in a long list rather than warping around the panel. Is there a way of achieving that effect without using a Warppanel?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, as Clemens pointed out, "The ItemsPanel must support virtualization. WrapPanel does not."